# "La mia famiglia" or "mia famiglia"?

Tags: word-usage, adjectives, articles

I am confused as I thought "mia famiglia" translated to "my family", but I was recently corrected and told it was "la mia famiglia"... What is the difference?

Comment: Just to add something more general to the good answers: the norm, in Italian and unlike English, is that you use the article before possessive adjective just like before nouns or other adjectives (*la famiglia*, *la grande famiglia*, *la mia famiglia*...). There are few exceptions to this, in particular those pointed out in CarLaTex's answer.

Answer (score 11):

In English the definite article must not be put before the possessive adjectives, in Italian in general is the contrary:

*Il mio vestito è blu* **correct**

*Mio vestito è blu* **wrong** (if you say it we understand immediately that you are a foreigner).

However, there is an exception with singular names which represent family members, for example:

*Mia cugina è logorroica* **correct**

*La mia cugina è logorroica* **wrong**

*Mio nonno faceva il muratore* **correct**

*Il mio nonno faceva il muratore* **wrong**.

With *famiglia* the definite article is necessary:

*La mia famiglia è di origini milanesi* **correct**

*Mia famiglia è di origini milanesi* **wrong**.

As egreg correctly pointed out, with *mamma* and *papà* or *babbo* both forms are used, maybe with a slightly different meaning, for example:

*La mia mamma è bella* I say this because I love my mother and for me she's beautiful

*Mia mamma è bella* I say this as a matter of fact, she's a beautiful woman.

Comment: On the other hand, *la mia mamma* or *il mio babbo/papà* are fairly common.

Comment: @egreg Thank you! I've edited my answer. Moreover in Milanese dialect we always put the article: *la me' zia*, *el mi' nonu* (I've written them as they are pronounced, since I cannot write in Milanese).

Comment: Where I live, the article is never used: *me mama*, *me opà*, *me zio*, *me nona*.

Comment: @egreg I think Milanese people put articles everywhere: also *la Carla*, *l'Enrico*... :)

Comment: Forse dire che "il mio nonno..." è *wrong* è un po' eccessivo. Forse è poco comune... poi mi sembra che in Toscana l'articolo in questi casi lo usino di più, magari perchè dicono "il mio figliolo".

Comment: @linuxfansaysReinstateMonica "Il mio figliolo" sì, ma "il mio figlio" no, a meno che non sia seguito da un aggettivo. "Il mio nonnino" potrebbe andare bene, ma "il mio nonno", a meno che non ci sia un aggettivo dopo, tipo "il mio nonno materno", non l'ho mai sentito... e qui a Milano mettiamo l'articolo anche davanti ai nomi propri :) Comunque il **wrong** era riferito all'intera frase.

Answer (score 1):

The definite article (or articolo determinativo in Italian) is used to reference a general category of people, animals, object or concepts.

In your case it is correct to translate **My family** with **La mia famiglia** (mind also the letter case) since also with the presence of the possessive adjective **mia**  the use of the definite article *la* is always required.

You can find a very good reference in this [Treccani Italian grammar](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/articoli-determinativi_(La-grammatica-italiana)/)

Answer (score 0):

With the singular of *sorella, fratello, figlio/a, mamma, papà, nonno/a*, etc. do not use the article either *il* or *la* with possessive (*mia sorella*, *mio fratello*).  With the plural forms of family members, use the articles *le* or  *i* plus possessive as in the examples *le mie sorelle, i miei fratelli, i miei nonni, le mie nonne, i miei genitori*, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Mia nonna and la mia nonna: both are ok, see M. Dardano "La lingua italiana" (Zanichelli), which also gives il mio papà, il mio babbo, la mia mamma, and not mio papà, mio babbo, mia mamma.
Clearly there are no correct answers here - except "Dipende".

Comment: Welcome! Please, consider that the question is not about “mia nonna” or “la mia nonna” and this is not a forum. I see that there is another off-topic answer.